# About ORACLE SQL Query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a three tables and I merged the tables like below. I want to print the name with an average of nine points for the title and reduce the year by ten.

| TITLE | YEAR | POINT | NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1999 | 9 | K |
| A | 1999 | 9 | L |
| C | 1997 | 7 | M |

For this, I wrote the following query but the query fails. What query should I write?

```
SELECT k.title, k.year, AVG(point), m.name
  FROM Table1 k 
  JOIN Table2 l ON (k.title=l.title) 
  JOIN Table3 m ON (l.year=m.year) 
 GROUP BY title;
```

Comment: You said it fails, why does it fail?  Does it cause error or not return your desired results or other?

Comment: It returned error.

Comment: Your `group by` columns are inconsistent with the `select` columns.  Beyond that, I can't help because you have no desired results and I can't follow the logic.

Answer (score 1):

if you connected the tables correctly, then it's an issue with the GROUP BY clause. If you are using aggregated functions such as (AVG,SUM,COUNT) in the Select clause, all other columns included in the select clause must be added in the group by clause. this should work:

```
SELECT k.TITLE, k.YEAR, AVG(POINT), m.NAME 
FROM Table1 k JOIN Table2 l ON (k.TITLE=l.TITLE) JOIN Table3 m ON (l.YEAR=m.YEAR) 
GROUP BY (k.TITLE, k.YEAR,m.NAME);
```

**Edit:**

If you want to substract years from the Select clause you can use ADD_MONTHS function like this:

```
SELECT k.TITLE, ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC(k.YEAR), -12*10 ), AVG(POINT), m.NAME 
FROM Table1 k JOIN Table2 l ON (k.TITLE=l.TITLE) JOIN Table3 m ON (l.YEAR=m.YEAR) 
GROUP BY (k.TITLE, ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC(k.YEAR), -12*10 ),m.NAME);
```

you also can add **WHERE** clause to your query and specify some conditions, the WHERE clause should be added before the **group by** clause and after the **FROM** clause.

you basically can replace any DATE data type column with `ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC(yourcolumn), -12*10 )` replacing (**yourcolumn**) with the column you want to substract years from.

best of luck to you.

Comment: Thanks for your query. How can I write a query that substract ten years from dates?

Comment: this will substract 10 years , you can change the number 10 to any number you want `SELECT SYSDATE , ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC(SYSDATE), -12*10 ) FROM DUAL`

Comment: How can I add this to the query above?

Comment: I added the substracting to the answer.